# how delete text before percentage and keep everything after the percentage in excel or notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV file which contains one column containing the following text for example:

```
hlasjdlajsdlasjdlasjdl  52% bawełna 3% elastan 45% poliamid
```

and in the following row:

```
khsalhsladhsldh  55% bawełna 45% poliester
```

I a need way to delete everything before the first percentage and have the following result:

Example 1 :

```
52% bawełna 3% elastan 45% poliamid
```

Example 2:

```
 55% bawełna 45% poliester
```

I think through Regex I can achieve that but am not that expert with regular expression; can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `^.+?(?=\d+%)`

This can be interpreted as:

```
^.*?(?=\d+%)
^             Line start
 .*?          Any number of any character, matching as few characters as possible
    (?=\d+%)  Match a percentage but don't select this
```

Just find-replace this with empty string

Comment: thanks for the answer  i tried and i have found all matches which is correct  but how can i delete the  text before the match. 

hope you will excuse my inexperience in such things

Comment: Note the Text which i need to delete is not the same in all row